OpenAI Whisper API: How do I shorten the response latency? How do I make Whisper respond quicker?
I am making a voice chatbot. The issue is that I needed to shorten the delay between finishing my sentence while speaking to the bot and the start of the bot's response, which currently takes about 6 seconds.
Using Sequential Sentence Chunking with OpenAI Whisper speech-to-text model to solve this problem?

Use the GPT-4o model instead of the Whisper model, as stated in the official OpenAI blog:

GPT-4o (“o” for “omni”) is a step towards much more natural
human-computer interaction—it accepts as input any combination of
text, audio, image, and video and generates any combination of text,
audio, and image outputs. It can respond to audio inputs in as little
as 232 milliseconds, with an average of 320 milliseconds, which is
similar to human response time (opens in a new window) in a
conversation. It matches GPT-4 Turbo performance on text in English
and code, with significant improvement on text in non-English
languages, while also being much faster and 50% cheaper in the API.
GPT-4o is especially better at vision and audio understanding compared
to existing models.

